# Why nginx -v not display version on ubuntu12.04?

Tags: 12.04, nginx

Nginx was installed on our ubuntu 12.04 server and we want to find the version. Here is what we did:

```
admin@ibm-testbox:/opt/nginx/sbin$ nginx -v
The program 'nginx' can be found in the following packages:
 * nginx-extras
 * nginx-full
 * nginx-light
 * nginx-naxsi
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
admin@ibm-testbox:/opt/nginx/sbin$ nginx -V
The program 'nginx' can be found in the following packages:
 * nginx-extras
 * nginx-full
 * nginx-light
 * nginx-naxsi
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Then we were trying to find if nginx was running. Here is the output:

```
admin@ibm-testbox:/opt/nginx/sbin$ ps waux | grep nginx
root      7652  0.0  0.0  37560  1100 ?        Ss   Dec20   0:00 nginx: master process /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx
nobody    7653  0.0  0.0  38008  2316 ?        S    Dec20   0:00 nginx: worker process
admin  23376  0.0  0.0   9388   924 pts/0    S+   08:35   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

The nginx was installed with PhusionPassenger module. Why nginx -v (-V) did not show version?

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like nginx is not properly installed.
You can re install nginx by

```
apt-get purge nginx*
apt-get autoremove
apt-get update
apt-get install nginx-full
```

Also you can try [easyengine](https://github.com/rtCamp/easyengine) to install and manage website on ubuntu server.

Comment: Very interesting! What could be the possible issue with nginx installation? Nginx was bundle installed with phusion passenger and has been serving our web app. Did it mean nginx was working fine?